# How to show non existence of an operator $A: V \to V^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space , $p \in (1,2)$ and $\mu >0.$ How can I prove that there does not exist an operator $A:V \to V^*$ such that 
$$\langle Au-Av, u-v\rangle \geq \mu \Vert u-v \Vert ^p,\qquad u, v \in V. $$

Comment: any additional assumptions on $A$, such as linearity or continuity?

Comment: No, but it is $p \in (1,2)$, edited it

Comment: $Au$ and $u$ are in different space which are a Banach space and its Dual. How can you do the inner product of them?

Comment: @LeB its not an inner product, its a duality product

Comment: @supinf I guess "operator" usually refers to linear operator?

Comment: @CaveJohnson usually you should specify. In this question, nonlinear and non-continuous operators are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an arbitrary point $v\in V$ such that $\|v\|=1$.

Let $n$ be an arbitrary integer.
(Our goal is a proof by contradiction as $n\to\infty$).

We consider the points $v_k:= \tfrac{k}{n} v$ for $k=0,\ldots, n$.
Then, by assumption we have
$$
 \langle A v_{k+1} - Av_k,v_{k+1}-v_k \rangle
 \geq
 \mu \| v_{k+1}-v_k\|^p
$$
for every $k=0,\ldots,n-1$.

Summing up those terms will lead to the inequality
$$
\tfrac 1n \langle Av - A0 , v \rangle \geq \mu n^{1-p}.
$$

For sufficiently large $n$, this cannot be true.